# Webusercontrol is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, asp.net, webusercontrol

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0122: 'Controls_Arcade_StarDisplay.Stars' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

I've checked other SO threads but can't make much sense of them.  This control is being used inside another webusercontrol.  Whenever I try and do anything with it it throws this error.  The class in question is this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="StarDisplay.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls_Arcade_StarDisplay" %>
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="Stars" />
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public partial class Controls_Arcade_StarDisplay : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public double Rating { get; set; }
    public string Tooltip { get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string CSSClass = "star-rating s-";
        if (Rating < 0.25)
            CSSClass += "0";
        else if (Rating < 0.75)
            CSSClass += "05";
        else if (Rating < 1.25)
            CSSClass += "1";
        else if (Rating < 1.75)
            CSSClass += "15";
        else if (Rating < 2.25)
            CSSClass += "2";
        else if (Rating < 2.75)
            CSSClass += "25";
        else if (Rating < 3.25)
            CSSClass += "3";
        else if (Rating < 3.75)
            CSSClass += "35";
        else if (Rating < 4.25)
            CSSClass += "4";
        else if (Rating < 4.75)
            CSSClass += "4";
        else if (Rating < 1.25)
            CSSClass += "1";
        else if (Rating < 4.75)
            CSSClass += "45";
        else
            CSSClass += "5";
        Stars.CssClass = CSSClass;

        if (Tooltip != null)
            Stars.ToolTip = Tooltip;
    }
}
```

The control is registered in web.config:

```
    <pages validateRequest="false" smartNavigation="false" clientIDMode="Static">
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="Scirra" src="~/Controls/Arcade/GameOverview.ascx" tagName="GameOverview"/>
            <add tagPrefix="Scirra" src="~/Controls/Arcade/Stars/StarDisplay.ascx" tagName="StarDisplay"/>
        </controls>
    </pages>
```

The start display control is appearing inside the game overview control.

Thanks for any help, completely stuck!  Other questions refer to getting properties of the controls I don't understand, or changing things in the designer I can't find either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that you have something in your user control called `Stars` and it is probably defined as `private` or `protected`.

The issue is that this is a Web Site and not a Web Application and in a Web Site, .Net automatically creates the `runat="server"` controls as `protected` properties, so they cannot be exposed outside of the User Control or its direct inheritors.

So there are two possible options:

1. Convert the web site to a web application. This will cause a designer file to be created that contains the definitions of the controls. You can then take the control out of the designer file, place it in your codebehind, and change the access level to public.
2. Since this is a control that will be accessed from other controls, a better design than exposing the control directly is to provide interaction methods that those other controls can use in order to encapsulate the behavior within this control. For example, exposing a `SetRating` method that accepts the rating and updates the `Stars` panel internally.

Option #2 is definitely a better option from a design standpoint.

Comment: I posted the entire class, changing `protected void Page_Load` to `public void Page_Load` throws the same error

Comment: What does the declaration of Stars look like in the designer file?

Comment: Sorry I've never really ever used the designer before, where is the designer file located?

Comment: I think it is generated as protected by default. What I usually do to avoid this is expose a public property or method in the regular code-behind (not designer) and share the control out that way. This may or may not be an option depending on your situation.

Comment: Two ways to get there: 1) right-click on the page and select View Code Gen File; 2) Show all files in the project, then expand your page; you will see it along with your codebehind.

Comment: The other trick that I forgot about: if you change the access level on the control, move the definition from the designer into your standard code-behind. This way, the designer shouldn't change the protection level back to protected (and, if it does, it will be more visible).

Comment: That's strange; can you select Stars in your code-behind, right-click on it, and select Go To Definition?

Comment: I get this error when doing go to definition: http://imgur.com/FwNsQ (Thanks for your help by the way)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5145/discussion-between-competent-tech-and-tom-gullen)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message with my control. I examined my code file and the answer became obvious. The procedure was defined as `void Register_Submit()`. I have added `public` to its definition, so it became `Public void Register_Submit()` and the error was gone.